# How to scope to team in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

I'm trying to update my repository permissions so that just developers in my team have access.
For 'Scoped' access it just lists 'Project Areas' :

[image]

Is it possible to select a 'Team Area' instead to restrict access to just developers in that team ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the possible access management restrictions detailed in "[Controlling access to source control in Rational Team Control](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#private_workspace)".

What you describe isn't possible for Repository workspace.

It is possible (with RTC4+ only) to [restrict work items for a certain team area](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#protect_some_workitems).
You can also look into stream ownership.

But regarding your own repo workspace, you can only limit it to member of project area, not of a team area.